# Can Vagrant provision a VM using an Ansible installation in another Vagrant VM?

Tags: vagrant, ansible, provisioning

I just started using Ansible and Vagrant to bootstrap a local development environment (let's call it *dev-server-1*) and the host is a Windows machine (*win-host*).

I have to provision *dev-server-1* machine using Ansible, but *win-host* is running Windows so I was wondering if I could use another Vagrant VM (*ansible-host*, running a minimal box with Ansible installed) just for Ansible, but leaving *dev-server-1* running on *win-host*. Is this feasible?

Comment: I've had success in the past using the method described here: http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2014/10/running-vagrant-with-ansible-provisioning-on-windows/ this may be tightly coupled to the Vagrant and Ansible version that was hacked against however.

Comment: Please look at my recent answer to a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34485973/543205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use the built in [Ansible provisioner](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html) in Vagrant as that relies on the host having both Ansible installed and also an OS that supports ControlPersist (which Windows doesn't).

You could however use Vagrant to spin up your bare VMs and then use a separate VM (possibly created by Vagrant) with Ansible installed to then configure these other VMs.

The only thing you would need for that is for there to be network connectivity between the VMs.

Unfortunately you will not be able to use the auto generated inventory that Vagrant creates on running an Ansible provisioner as it requires an Ansible provisioner to be run. As far as I know there is no way to get this inventory without running the Ansible provisioner.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was thinking, hoping that I missed something :)

Answer (score 2):

I have proposed a solution in this question:
[Provision Vagrant Linux VM with another Vagrant Linux VM running Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416134/provision-vagrant-linux-vm-with-another-vagrant-linux-vm-running-ansible/33422095?noredirect=1#comment54634698_33422095)

Which I think it can work for you as well it's basically to provision the vagrant box using shell to install ansible on your guest and to run ansible against your localhost(on your vagrant box).

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what @ydaetskcoR is suggesting in his/her answer.